# How to make visible infinite movieclips with one button?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on an interactive map in Actionscript-3 (Adobe Flash CS6).

What I'm trying to do is, with a single button, to show multiple objects (movieclips) with each mouse click.

I'm currently working with this code, but I can't manage to find out how to show multiple movieclips, I can only show ONE:

```
btn_ally_unit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mostrar_ally_unit2);

function mostrar_ally_unit2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    map_editor.ally_unit.visible = true;

}
```

How do I extend this to apply to any number of movieclips?

Comment: Where these _"infinite!"_ number of object are stored? in an array or what?!

Comment: Its just a movieclip stored in the... library?

With the code posted before I can only manage to make visible one image (one movieclip). 

I would like to create (or to make visible) one more image (movieclip) at a time, each time the button is clicked.

BTW thanks for the answer

Comment: do you try to cloning that single `ally_unit` ? is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure by infinite you mean indefinite.

Target the unit clicked by using the `target` property of the Event class.  Looks something like this:

```
btn_ally_unit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mostrar_ally_unit2);

function mostrar_ally_unit2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.visible = true;

}
```

You see?  `(event:MouseEvent)` is saying that this function expects one argument (a MouseEvent) which you are giving the variable name of `event`. That's a convention but I like to use `me` as an abbreviation for mouse event. Others just use the letter `e`. Ok. Now `event` has a property, `target`, which is the thing receiving the event. In this case it will be one of your units. Your units have a property of `visible` which you can toggle off like you have been doing but by using the relative mouse event target, you can use the same line of code for all units.

**note**

Of course you must add the event listener to each unit. You could make it part of the class or just add it when a new unit is instantiated.

**note**

Using the event flow in actionscript 3 can be tricky. Seek out a tutorial on this. Here is one [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html) related to event flow from Adobe.

Comment: My second note says "using the event flow can be tricky". Don't misunderstand this. When you use an event you are using the default pattern of the event flow. One can not choose to use or not use the flow. So what I mean is the event flow, as it stands in as3, is not always intuitive, but it is much more versatile and powerful than previous AS releases. Usually the defaults work just fine though. So try what I suggested and see if it works. If it doesn't it might be because the event.target might first be the stage! Let me know if the link I posted doesn't help solve that problem.